# Django - What does objects.get return

Tags: python, django

Sorry if this seems like a really stupid question. I am building an app using Django, and at some point I am accessing the db using `db.objects.get(var = val)`

But my question is what type object does this method return? And hw can I access the data in it?
Like as a `dict`, `list` or sth else?

When I use this:

```py
a = db.objects.get(var=val)
print(a["id"])
```

It returns:

```py
'db' object is not subscriptable
```

When I use this:

```py
a = db.objects.get(var=val)
print(a)
```

I get:

```
db object (1)
```

I cannot use the data in this form.

Comment: There's a ton of information about it. You can start by reading the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return a object. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) for details.

Use  .  operator to access values inside object.

```
print(a.field_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, how can I get the data in it? Currently when I use `print(db.objects.get(var=val))` it returns `db object (1)`

Comment: Store it in a variable. Then the values inside returned object can be accessed like you access values in dictonary.

Comment: it returns `'db' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Try the  . Operator to access value instead of square brackets

Answer (score 0):

It would return the object of your model on which you are querying.
If nothing matches and no rows is returned, it would through a Model.DoesNotExists exception.